# Why configure options in AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme<TOptions, THandler> does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

second parameter of .AddScheme (Action) does not do anything.

```
services
                .AddAuthentication(AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddScheme<JwtAuthenticationOptions, JwtAuthenticationHandler>(AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtAuthenticationScheme, 
                    jwtAuthOptions => jwtAuthOptions.KeyStorageFolderPath = Configuration.GetSection("KEYSTORAGE_PATH").Value);
```

My custom authentication options class:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        internal readonly CryptographyKeysStorage KeysStorage;

        private string _keyStorageFolderPath;
        public string KeyStorageFolderPath
        {
            get { return _keyStorageFolderPath; }
            set { _keyStorageFolderPath = value; }
        }
        public JwtAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            KeysStorage = new CryptographyKeysStorage(_keyStorageFolderPath);
        }
    }
```

Static class for schema name:

```
 public static class AuthenticationSchemeConstants
    {
        public const string JwtAuthenticationScheme = "jwt";
    }
```

Problem is that Action which I pass to AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme as second parameter does not do anything, that is, my `KeyStorageFolderPath` property in JwtAuthenticationOptions remains null and does not get value from appsettings.json which i'm trying to pass in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

asp.net core 3.1

Comment: Are you sure that `Configuration.GetSection("KEYSTORAGE_PATH").Value` isn't `null`?

Comment: @abdusco yes i've set it to separate variable and checked in debug mode, it is getting value from json

Answer (score 2):

As we all know, options are register as singleton.

Therefore, would it be a waste to let a block of code run to set the same static result for every request ?
If that so, we should only execute the execution config once, do we ?
But when and where we execute the config ?

That's all our freedom.

As behind the screen, `AddScheme<TOption, THandler>` only register the configuration along with it's config as singleton, the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/95b968014f16c3e1b61d1b830022484b9d0db187/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72).

And this is how it should act in detail:

Define the option:

```
public class SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public string IGonna { get; set; }
    }
```

Register the scheme:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
                {
                    opts.DefaultScheme = CommonConstants.SessionAuthentication;
                    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = CommonConstants.SessionAuthentication;
                })
                .AddScheme<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions, SystemAuthenticationRelatedHandler>(
                    CommonConstants.SessionAuthentication, x => x.IGonna = "get a vodka");
```

Use the config:

```
public class SystemAuthenticationRelatedHandler : AuthenticationHandler<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions>
    {
        private readonly SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions _option;

        public SystemAuthenticationRelatedHandler(IOptionsMonitor<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock,
            IConfigureOptions<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions> config) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            // This is just some dummy logic
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.CurrentValue.IGonna))
            {
                var optionConfig = config as IConfigureNamedOptions<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions>;
                optionConfig!.Configure(CommonConstants.SessionAuthentication, options.CurrentValue);
            }

            _option = options.CurrentValue;
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In real project, you shouldn't put the config here.
If your condition and resources are static, config them somewhere in the Program.cs file which will get execute only one time would be nice.

Comment: sorry but I don't get your answer. the problem is that x => x.IGonna = "get a vodka" will not be hit by debugger

Comment: You propably want to check your code again... i just re-testing the solution and it works fine... both on .net core 3.1 and 5. Let me know if you want a scren capture

Comment: Just made a quick recap what i just test... [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plSTSM2OpZs)

Answer (score 0):

Before you AddAuthentication you need Configure the Options

```
    services
    .Configure<SystemSessionAuthenticationRelatedOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.KeyStorageFolderPath = Configuration.GetSection("KEYSTORAGE_PATH").Value
    }
   .AddAuthentication(AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtAuthenticationScheme)
   .AddScheme<JwtAuthenticationOptions, JwtAuthenticationHandler>(AuthenticationSchemeConstants.JwtAuthenticationScheme, 
                    jwtAuthOptions => jwtAuthOptions.KeyStorageFolderPath = Configuration.GetSection("KEYSTORAGE_PATH").Value);
```